# Access denied in creating schema on MySql Cluster

Tags: mysql

I'm unable to create a schema on freshly set-up MySql Cluster 7.4.7 on single windows machine. It fails with error `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my_schema'`. What is it that I'm missing? During installation I was not asked for username and password for MySql, so what are the defaults?

Also to give detail on how I set-up (in case that is not proper), I following [this](http://downloads.mysql.com/tutorials/cluster/mysql_wp_cluster_quickstart.pdf) tutorial and using default settings on new cluster wizard, I have been able to successfully run 2 Multithreaded data node (ndbmtd.exe), 1 Management Node (ndb_mgmd.exe), 2 SQL Node (mysqld.exe). I also stopped mysql server 5.5 running on my machine previously. Then, using command line and typing `mysql` I'm able to connect and `show databases;` result in 2 schemas:

information_schema

test

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further trying, I've been able to get away with both the problems above:

1. Instead of `create schema`, I used `create database` and it worked.
2. By default there is no password. I'm able to connect with user as `root` without any password.